# What are "irreducible factors" in a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I am really not understanding what "irreducible factor" in $F[X]$ for field $F$ means. can someone explain?

for example is $(x - 1)^2$ irreducible? in my current understanding I think yes. but I have no idea

thanks

Comment: What you give is irreducibility of *polynomial* in a polynomial ring $\;F[x]\;$ . That $\;F\;$ is a field doesn't mean the factors are there.

Comment: @Joanpemo i don't think i understand what you wrote.. care to elaborate?

Comment: "Irreducibility" is a term from ring theory (at least in conection to what you ask), and indeed: a polynomial $\;f(x)\in F[x]\;$ is irreducible if it cannot be expressed as $\;f(x)=h(x)g(x)\;,\;\;h,g\in F[x]\;$, with $\;h,g\;$ **not** being units or associates of $\;f(x)\;$ . Thus, for example, $\;(x-1)^2\;$ is **not** irreducible (i.e., it is reducible), since $\;(x-1)^2=(x-1)(x-1)\;$ , and $\;(x-1)\;$ isn't a unit nor an associate of $\;(x-1)^2\;$ .

Comment: $(x-1)^2$ is _reducible_ because it's a second degree polynomial that can be written as the product of the two first-degree polynomials $(x-1)$ and $(x-1)$. If $F = \Bbb R$, then the only irreducible polynomials are the first-degree polynomials, as well as the second-degree polynomials with complex roots, like $x^2 + x + 1$. If $F = \Bbb Q$, then how to tell whether a polynomial is reducible or not has been the subject of _much_ study, and as far as I know we're far from anything resembling a solution, except in the simplest cases (like degree four or lower).

Comment: $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain using the degree as the Euclidean function, and the degree of a nonzero constant is taken as zero, but $0$ itself has no degree defined

Comment: @Arthur That's true, as you mention, in the very particular case that $\;F=\Bbb R\;$ . For other fields, and thus other polynomial rings, that's false and it seems to be the asker meant a more general question.

Comment: @Joanpemo and Arthur thanks. this makes things much more clear. Will Jagy I have no idea what you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

an irreducible element in $F[X ]$, $F$ field, is a non constant polynomial $P$ such that if $Q$ is a non constant polynomial and divided $ P  $ then P = aQ where $a \in F$.
the exemple indicated is so not irreducible. But is factored as factor product irreducibles that is $(x-1)$